# How to mask a ViewController when presenting a view over it

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to mask a ViewController when i present a view like in [image: this screenshot.] The way i present my view is by anchoring it outside of the screen like this:

```
addContactTopAnchor = addContact.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
view.topAnchor)
addContactTopAnchor.isActive = true
addContact.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
addContact.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 182).isActive = true
```

and when i press a button i move it onto the display like this:

```
 func addTapped(){
        self.addContactTopAnchor.isActive = false
        self.addContactTopAnchor =  addContact.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 182)
        self.addContactTopAnchor.isActive = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

I want to mask everything except for the view just like its show in my screenshot.

Comment: Lay a transparent black UIView and animate it's alpha in your animation block? Don't forget to remove the view when you are done.

Comment: I tried this but the mask also covers the view that i am animating up, is there a way i can get this view to be on top of the one that i am using as a mask?

Comment: actually i just figured it out thanks, i was able to bring it to the front with             self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.addContact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a view

```
let mask: UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .black
    view.alpha = 0
    return view
}()
```

and in my button press, I set the alpha and brought my view to the front

```
func addTapped() {
    self.addContactTopAnchor.isActive = false
    self.addContactTopAnchor =  addContact.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -182)
    self.addContactTopAnchor.isActive = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.mask.alpha = 0.5
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.5
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: self.addContact)
    })
}
```

EDIT: Also i added this to mask the navigation bar:

```
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.5
      self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

thanks @desdenova for the help